# how to move a line from one window to another?

Tags: frames

I have two files open, shown in two windows.

Some lines in one file belong in the other file.

I could cut the line here, move to the other window, paste there, and come back. That's a lot of work with so many lines to go through.

There does not seem to be any existing command that would do the work, so how do I write an elisp function (or macro?), and bind it to an available key/chord, to do that?

This is similar to the problem solved by diff-mode and the like, but the files here are not related, so a diff doesn't make sense.

**[edit 1]**
very good point raised by @StarBug. I see several possibilities (a configuration variable?), listed from top to bottom: a. move at the top, b. move at point, c. move to 'same' line on screen, d. move to bottom.

**[edit 2]**
fixed the confusion between frame and window.

Comment: I like the idea of a function that facilitates copy/paste between two frames in some clever way. However, I am sure exactly what you want. How would the function "know" where to paste the text in frame 2?

Comment: Just to be sure: You do mean frames, not Emacs windows, right?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @StarBug, one UI problem will be how to specify the "other" buffer/frame.

But you could start with something like:

```
(defun my-command (beg end)
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (line-beginning-position)
           (line-beginning-position 2))))
  (let ((line (delete-and-extract-region beg end)))
    (with-selected-frame (other-frame)
      (insert line))))
```